# Is Patent No. : 9,717,352 Issue Date : August 1, 2017 valid in India

Tags: international, india

Is Patent No. : 9,717,352 Issue Date : August 1, 2017 in US is valid in India

Answer (score 1):

US patents are effective only in the US. I could find no foreign equivalents so there should be no coverage in India.

Comment: Better search in the Indian Patent Office by Applicsnt, etc. sometimes are hiden.

Comment: @HenriqueRaminhos excellent suggestion. If you could, it would merit a separate answer.